# MySQL PHP Grabbing rows not relevant to query

Tags: php, mysql

I have no clue what I could be doing wrong. This has only ever happened with the Change logs that I've been trying to develop. I coded this from scratch, and it really couldn't be much simpler.

For some reason when I try to grab rows that are only
`is_dev='1'` (Is in development)
OR 
`planned='1'` (Is planned)
AND
`website_id='13'` (ID of website)

It shows a result from another website `ID ("9")`.

This is my current query:

`**$getdev = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM changelog_entries WHERE in_dev='1' OR planned='1' AND website_id='13' ORDER BY id DESC");**`

This is what I get in return, I wrote on the picture what website id they belong to.
https://img.rnjrweb.com/errorchangelogs.PNG

I've also tried this query:

`**$getdev = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM changelog_entries WHERE website_id='13' AND in_dev='1' OR planned='1' ORDER BY id DESC");**`
 and when I do, it returns even more irrelevant rows.

Any clues? I'm pretty stuck here. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need parenthesis around your OR:

```
SELECT * FROM changelog_entries WHERE (in_dev='1' OR planned='1') AND website_id='13' ORDER BY id DESC
```

If you don't put them any website_id row having in_dev=1 will match.